# Interested in what the "<<" does

Tags: ruby

Came across this code.

```
def setup(&block)
  @setups << block
end
```

What does this line do?

```
@setups << block
```

Interested in what the does "<<".

The manual says that it is the operator of double shift, but he is here with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an array `<<` is the append method. It adds an item to the end of the array.

So in your specific case when you call `setup` with a block the `Proc` object made from the block is stored in `@setups`.

Note: as [sbeam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125875/sbeam) points out in his comment, because `<<` is a method, it can do different things depending on the type of object it is called on e.g. concatenation on strings, bit shifting on integers etc.

See the "[ary << obj → ary](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)" documentation.

Comment: it actually is not an operator, it's just a funny name for a method. You are calling the `<<` method on the object, which in the case of an Array is equivalent to `push` and for a String is equivalent to `+`. `<<` is also referred to as the "Bitwise Shift Left operator", but this actually means when you call `<<` on an Integer, it performs a leftwards bit shift. I'm being pedantic, but it's kinda important to understand in Ruby, since they can be redefined and change in function based on the receiving object.

Comment: @sbeam yes, you're right. I was oversimplifying a bit in the answer and agree that it is an important distinction to understand within Ruby. Will update the answer to improve it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's building an array by pushing elements onto the end of it.

Here's the [manual entry](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Answer (score 1):

`<<` in Ruby is commonly used to mean *append* - *add* to a list or *concatenate* to a string.

The reason Ruby uses this is unclear but may be because the library largely distinguishes between changing an object and returning a changed object (methods that change the objects tend to have a `!` suffix). In this way, `<<` is the change-the-object counterpart to `+`.

Comment: Ruby uses it because other languages also use it to mean the same thing.