# double less than ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interested in what the “<<” does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511446/interested-in-what-the-does)

I read [Ruby class inheritance: What is `<<` (double less than)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182628/ruby-class-inheritance-what-is-double-less-than). I understood it helps to create methods for instances (kind of inheritance). But I came across a code:

```
threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|
h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
puts "Fetching: #{myPage}"
resp, data = h.get('/', nil )
puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{resp.message}"
}
```

where `threads` is an array. Could somebody explain the usage of `<<` with objects instead of classes?

Comment: `<<` appends onto an array. So a new `Thread` object is added to the `threads` array.

Answer (score 11):

The `<<` operator can be overloaded to do essentially anything, because it's *just a method*. A class is free to define its own behaviour for the `<<` operator. In this case, `threads` is an array or array-like object, and typical array semantics use `<<` as an alias for `push`. The code is simply appending a new `Thread` onto an array called `threads`.