# Rails newbie: What does "<<" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blacklight

I am trying to add advanced search facilities to a Blacklight installation, but I know slim to nil about rails.

I am stuck in a (so far great) tutorial that states:

```
Turn this feature on by adding to your CatalogController definition:
self.search_params_logic << :add_advanced_parse_q_to_solr
```

I can find my CatalogController, but I have no clue where to put the "<< :add_advanced_parse_q_to_solr" thingie.

Is it a part of the class definition in the top? As it is now it says:

```
class CataligController < ApplicationController
```

Am I supposed to exchange the "< ApplicationController" with "<< :add_advanced_parse_q_to_solr", or should I just append it?

What does the ":" mean, and what does the "<<" mean?

If anyone have any good references to tutorials that can teach me these (I guess) basic syntaxes, please post them here - I would love to understand what I am doing instead of just copy/pasting me my way through!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interested in what the "<<" does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511446/interested-in-what-the-does)

Comment: asked multiple times here. just google it and you'll get ton of SO answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The added line should appear within your `CatalogController` definition, so...

```
class CatalogController < ApplicationController
  self.search_params_logic << :add_advanced_parse_q_to_solr
```

The `<` operation shows class inheritance in the first line.
The `<<` operation means add the value on the right as a new element to the array on the left.  An equivalent way would be to use the array push method...

self.search_params_logic.push(:add_advanced_parse_q_to_solr)

Which brings us to the question about what `.` means... it simply means you're calling a method that is part of an object or object's class.

For example

```
"Hasse".downcase
=> "hasse"
```

Strings have a method downcase, and in the above line you're calling that method on the string and the result will be returned.

`self.search_params_logic` means you're calling a method on `self` (in this case, `self` is the `CatalogController` so you could have also done `CatalogController.search_params_logic` but it's not very elegant).

The `search_params_logic` returns an array and you can manipulate the array... add or remove elements, for example.

Comment: I can't tell if this is sarcasm or not, but very full explanation +1

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation. I knew what the "." meant, but not the ":". But thanks anyway. I will read up on Ruby right away! :-)

Comment: Ah, I misread your message... "."  and ":" look very similar on my monitor! Anything with a leading `:` is a symbol, which is just a concept with a name.  This video discusses symbols... it's not a perfect video but he does a good job... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBXGBbEbXZY

Comment: @Yule no sarcasm. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `array << "something"` is just adding of new element into the `array`. And `:something` - is a symbol. You should learn basic syntax of Ruby language before using Rails. Start from the official site: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/.

Comment: Thanks to you too. And of course you are right - I should (and will) read up on Ruby. I just needed the darn thing to work, in order to do some frontend work on the markup and the js (which is my homeground).